# If a girl and a boy decided to stop being in a relationship and wait until allah brings them together ..is it permissible?

Tags: nikah, relationships, family, love, family-planning

I've had a crush on a boy when I was small cause of his character,personality and everything.but I never told anyone about it and prayed to allah daily for his goodness,health and everything.i didnt see him after he changed school.but I had hope and never stopped praying to allah for his success both in world and akhirah.i had no idea where he was still didn't give up. While scrolling through social media I found him and even though I didn't want any relationship at that moment I wanted to tell how much he meant to me.that moment I came to know he had loved me too but he didn't know how to say and he thought that I was a good girl and won't take it in a nice way.but we started talking casually. But later on decided to stop for the sake of allah and wait until our marriage. And let him bring the proposal and let it be a proper halal arranged marriage and no one needs to know about the past except him,me and Allah..is this the right decision?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum

A muslim woman must not even chat with a non-mahram except in case of necessity.

It is good that you did not meet each other as it would have resulted in major sins.

If a man and a woman (who are non-mahrams to each other are alone) then know that the third is shaitan.

The goal of shaitan is to misguide people and make them disobey Allah. Actually he wants more and more people to go the hell along with him.

**Read some articles :**

(i) https://islamqa.info/en/answers/47405/he-is-in-love-with-a-girl-and-wants-to-marry-her

(ii) https://islamqa.info/en/answers/9465/why-is-it-forbidden-for-a-man-and-a-woman-who-are-not-mahrams-to-have-a-relationship

(iii) https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10221/what-is-the-ruling-on-girls-corresponding-with-boys

(iv) Some useful books : https://islamqa.info/en/books

May Allah guide you and correct all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Allah has made us with the desire to come together, men and women, and He has warned us in the Holy Qur'an that from this, we are vulnerable for seduction. You are right that you want to find out whether it is the Will of Allah that you come together in marriage or not.
I would ask a woman whom you trust to discern the Answer of God from the seduction to ask Allah in silent prayer. If the answer is Yes, tell your Wali, if it's no, tell it to the man you have chatted with.